# How to solve:IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find all the peaks in an XRF spectrum to fit them. For the fit I will use LMFIT GaussianModel.
I am having a type problem ==> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Below the script I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import exp, pi, sqrt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel, LinearModel


# Define Gaussian for fit
def gaussian(x, amplitude, center, width):
    return (amplitude / (sqrt(2*pi) * width)) * exp(-(x-center)**2 / (2*width**2))

# Define function to open data file
def Read_Two_Column_File(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as data:
        x = []
        y = []
        for line in data:
            p = line.split()
            x.append(float(p[0]))
            y.append(float(p[1]))

    return x, y

# Open the data
x, y = Read_Two_Column_File('XRF_spectrum.txt')

#plot the data
plt.plot(x, y, 'b-', label='XRF_spectrum')
plt.show()

# find peaks
x_arr = np.array(x)
y_arr = np.array(y)

peaks = find_peaks(x_arr, threshold=100)
plt.plot(x_arr)
plt.plot(peaks, x_arr[peaks])
plt.show()
```

the error is in line plt.plot(peaks, x_arr[peaks]). I know that I cannot index a numpy array with a float number, but my data are float numbers...how can I get around this?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.signal.find_peaks` returns two values: a `peaks` array that has the indices of the peaks, and a `properties` dictionary.   You're putting those into one object.  So you probably want:

```
peaks, properties = find_peaks(x_arr, threshold=100)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves the issue, and creates a new one. When I try to print the peaks it results in an empty array, if I plot as in the script above, the result is a line.